# Por qué muestra cantidad equivocada de Caracteres en Consola?

Tags: java

Por qué  imprime tantos `">>>>>>>>>>" "<<<<<<<<<<"` si la condicional es: `"System.out.print( fila % 2 == 1 ? "<" : ">" );"`

```
public class Misterio3 
{
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      int fila = 10;
      int columna;

      while ( fila >= 1 ) 
      {
         columna = 1;

         while ( columna <= 10 ) 
         {
            System.out.print( fila % 2 == 1 ? "<" : ">" );
            ++columna;
         } // fin de while

         --fila;
         System.out.println();
      } // fin de while
   } // fin de main

} // fin de la clase Misterio3
```

Comment: **¿Qué resultado espera obtener?** es normal que imprima `10` caracteres dado que el `while` así lo valida.  `while ( columna <= 10 ) {..}`

Comment: hay le estas diciendo que te imprima 10 veces los "<" y los ">"

Comment: y estas usando while es decir si la condicion se cumple 10 veces, 10 veces te arrojara el resultado

Comment: Pues no veo ninguna condicional que limite en que momento se va a imprimir y en que momento no se va a imprimir.

Comment: Si dices que es normal que imprima 10 caracteres dado que el while así lo valida. while ( columna <= 10 ) {..}

Entonces porque en este ejemplo que el while es igual no salen tantos caracteres

public class Misterio2 
{
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      int cuenta = 1;

      while ( cuenta <= 10 ) 
      {
         System.out.println( cuenta % 2 == 1 ? "<" : ">" );
         ++cuenta;
      } // fin de while
   } // fin de main

} // fin de la clase Misterio2

Comment: @RobertoJoseSalasVega porque en ese ejemplo se usa `System.out.println` es decir , **después de imprimir el carácter añade un salto de línea**  ,  en su código usa `System.out.print` por eso le salen en una sola línea. dado que este no añade el salto de linea

Comment: tienes dos while, cada while lo imprime 5 veces... -.- en el que pones de ejemplo en el comentario sólo tiene un while.

Comment: @Dev.Joel quizas seria buena idea que sobre su comentario dejara una respuesta, entre otras cosas por el tema de preguntas respondidas ratio, ect. pero solo es una idea. Saludos